# Is HealthTap developed using phonegap cordova?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cross-platform

Need to check weather "HealthTap" is developed in phone gap or not?

I am seeing "HealthTap" is featured Application on Phonegap website but when i extracted IPA file, it doesn't contain phonegap.js or cordova.js.

Can you please help to detect weather it is developed in Phonegap or native?

Comment: I don't know what's used for developed HealthTap but I'm sure they won't use PhoneGap in the feature https://www.healthtap.com/work_with_us/jobs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is fourth on this list: http://www.rishabhsoft.com/blog/best-phonegap-apps
Along with the Wikipedia app, DHS Program, Paylution and TripCase.